# Быстро грохнуть много данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

Предположим, есть здоровенная БД.
В этой бд есть около 10 таблиц, которые взаимосвязаны между собой.
С этой БД работают службы и идут непрерывные вствки.

В общем, вопрос:

Как можно незаметно для пользователей, грохнуть из БД много данных за определенных период, что бы не подвесить клиентов, которые работают с БД?

Есть ли какие-нибудь интересные способы, кроме удаления небольшими порциями?

Comment: была у нас такая задача, нужно было убрать пару миллиардов записей. В итоге все сошлось к удалению порциями в периоды простоя в работе клиентов, остальное не взлетело по разным причинам. Так что я думаю что других вариантов нет, впрочем подождем...

Comment: Если остается совсем немного данных, то есть смысл перегрузить их в другую базу, переключиться на нее, а файлы первой просто физически (на уровне ОС) удалить.

Comment: @avp всем хорош вариант, кроме одного, если данные пополняются постоянно, то может потеряться часть данных, которые были внесены последними. Придется брать технологическое окно для переключения, а это уже будет заметно пользователям, хотя если сервер не работает в режиме 24х7 и база небольшая, то пожалуй, лучший

Comment: @rdorn, согласен. Тут наверное нужен совет хорошего DBA, как можно использовать журнал, чтобы изменения, начиная с некоторого момента накапливались в нем, а потом этот журнал надо накатить на новую базу.

Comment: _"интересные способы"_ да пожалуй, что и нет. Minimal logging для `delete` пока нет. Разве что `truncate ... with partition` (начиная с SqlServer 2016), но для этого таблица должна быть секционирована и сняты FK-ограничения, ссылающиеся на неё. Снятие FK-ограничений требует `Sch-M` блокировки (монопольная) на parent и referenced таблицах. Впрочем, это metadata-only операция и она должна быть достаточно быстрой. Обратное включение FK-ограничений `with nocheck` - также metadata-only. Включение `with check` может занять время (возможно приемлемое, если бОльшая часть данных будет удалена).

Answer (score 1):

Предложенное решение в комментрии @avp наиболее правильное:

- переместить необходимые данные в новую схему
- предоставить её пользователям
- старую удалить